# iOS App with OCMaps crashes when using the phone in chinese Language

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps

I've been given the task of doing maintenance to a iOS application that uses OCMapView.

I have just realized that when using the application in chinese language, it blows up when the selector doClustering is invoked on a OCMapView instance.

This is for me a very puzzling behaviour, because I thought that regardless of the environment language, the OCMapView class should always have the same methods. Am I wrong?

Do you have any recommendations about how to find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a quite silly problem: The translated xib file was cofigured to instantiate a MKMapView instead of a OCMapView.